# add column denoting window with certain ending time (but various window lengths)

Tags: r

I have a data.frame:

```
       value time
1      1    3
2      2    6
3      3    9
4      4   12
5      5   15
6      6   18
7      7   21
8      8    0
9      9    3
10    10    6
11    11   18
12    12    6
```

And I would like to add a column denotes a window from `6` to following value before `6`. Ie:

```
   value time window
1      1    3      3
2      2    6      3
3      3    9      2
4      4   12      2
5      5   15      2
6      6   18      2
7      7   21      2
8      8    0      2
9      9    3      2
10    10    6      2
11    11   18      1
12    12    6      1
```

The actual value of `window` doesn't matter as long as it can be used to make these groups.

(If anyone can think of a better title for this question by all means edit. This was the best I could come up with but don't think its particularly clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be create a logical vector on the `rev`erse of 'time', do cumulative sum and `rev`erse the output

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(window = rev(cumsum(rev(time) == 6)))
#    value time window
#1      1    3      3
#2      2    6      3
#3      3    9      2
#4      4   12      2
#5      5   15      2
#6      6   18      2
#7      7   21      2
#8      8    0      2
#9      9    3      2
#10    10    6      2
#11    11   18      1
#12    12    6      1
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df1$window <-  with(df1, rev(cumsum(rev(time) == 6)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(value = 1:12, time = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 
21L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```